# Copy files already exists and ignore source folder structure

Tags: batch-file

I need to replace files in destination with ignore source structure.
Basicly source folder have many subfolders, destination is only one folder without the subfolders so I tried Xcopy but the result is not good.

I have another folder with same issue I beleive the solution for the upper question will solve both.

Drop folder from TFS get everytime different name, I need to be able to copy from buildoutput folder(parent folder for all builds) only existing files to destination, destination doesn't include folders.

Comment: When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem. This is called creating a minimal, reproducible example (reprex), a minimal, complete and verifiable example (mcve), or a minimal, workable example (mwe). Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As best as I can tell from your question:

```
@echo off

set "src=C:\Your\Source\Directory"
set "des=C:\Your\Destination\Folder"

for /r "%src%" %%A in (*) do (
    if exist "%des%\%%~nxA" copy /y "%%A" "%des%\%%~nxA"
)
```

Will loop through all files in your source directory, check to see if those files exist in your destination folder, and if they do it will copy/overwrite them.

Reference: [For](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html), [Copy](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html).

If you're trying to accomplish something more specific you'll need to edit your question.